# Where can I access official online Rails API docs for previous versions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Now that Rails 5 is released, http://api.rubyonrails.org/ only has the docs for version 5.0.0.  How can I get to the official docs for Rails 4.2 or other previous versions?

I am aware of [apidock.com/rails](http://apidock.com/rails) and others, but I want the 4.2 docs from [api.rubyonrails.org](http://api.rubyonrails.org/).

Comment: http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find that document right over here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/

Just replace the `4.2` with the version you need (keeping the `v`) and most of the time you'll get the proper document.